# Apparently I’m calling random numbers but there's nothing in the call log

Tags: iphone

For the last few weeks I’ve had random calls from people saying that I called them, but there is nothing in my call log. I'm running the latest iOS.

Any suggestions as to what is happening here, and should I be alarmed enough to restore my phone?

Comment: This has been reported for almost a year by some users.  Have you performed the normal troubleshooting like force-closing the phone app, restarting your phone, etc?

Comment: @fsb: That's not helpful. The problem has nothing to do with the OP's phone but rather with criminals and criminally-negligent VoIP providers.

Comment: Kind of surprising that they returned the call; without revealing your PII, did you try to to get info on why they called "you" back? Are they totally "random"? Perhaps you might be a target of phishing from "fake call".

Comment: Yeah completely random, my number is German and I’ve had calls from a few random European countries. And the callers never ask for anything, not that I would tell them anything.

Comment: @R.. I'm pointing out to the OP that this issue has been reported as an iOS issue, not a criminal issue, for many people for over a year.  The resolution many have found is simply performing the standard restart, force restart, airplane mode, etc, steps.  It could be robocallers but it also has been seen in non-robocalling situations.  I recommend you do some research before you label someone trying to assist as 'not helpful'.

Comment: @fsb: It's been reported because the people reporting do not understand spoofing and how scams work. People's phones are not randomly calling strange numbers.

Comment: @R.. I disagree, based on what I've read from several site posts over the last year.  Regardless, instead of commenting to me you should add an answer to the OP so you can tell them how to handle this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These calls are not likely coming from your phone.  Rather, some robo caller is likely spoofing the caller ID using your number.  [The FCC website says](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/spoofing-and-caller-id)

> What can you do if your number is being spoofed?
>
> If you get calls from people saying your number is showing up on their
>   caller ID, it's likely that your number has been spoofed. We suggest
>   first that you do not answer any calls from unknown numbers, but if
>   you do, explain that your telephone number is being spoofed and that
>   you did not actually make any calls. You can also place a message on
>   your voicemail letting callers know that your number is being spoofed.
>   Usually scammers switch numbers frequently. It is likely that within
>   hours they will no longer be using your number.

Answer (score 3):

Contact you carrier/provider to verify that those calls are taking place on your account. If it turns out to be bogus, your carrier/provider probably has a procedure to deal with spoofing.

Answer (score 0):

to add to the above answer, usually a spoofed number lasts for a few hours. this could also be happening by a possible 3rd part app that has been allowed access to make phone calls

Comment: iOS apps are not able to make phone calls without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This practice is likely what is often called “neighbor spoofing” and has nothing to do with your phone.